# Relationship clasess has attribute error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, nomethoderror

Why relationship classes attribute is not attribute?

```
$ rs = ResourceServer.new
 => #<ResourceServer id: nil, resource_id: nil, server_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 

$ rs = ResourceServer.attributes = {:server_id => 1, :resource_id => 1}
 NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes=' for #<Class:0x00000003384728>
```

Model:

```
class ResourceServer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :server
  belongs_to :resource

  # Validations
...
end
```

Comment: Please add your model to your question :)

Comment: Try to add attr_accessible :server_id, :resource_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just because your are calling the `#attributes=` instance method on the class `ResourceServer` and not on the object `rs`.

What you want to do is:

```
rs.attributes = {:server_id => 1, :resource_id => 1}
```

And it will work! :)

Answer (score 0):

ResourceServer is a class, you need an instance of that class in order to assign attributes to it. For example you can do:

```
rs = ResourceServer.new
rs.attributes = {:server_id => 1, :resource_id => 1}
```